# Modifying column names of dataframes within a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe, lapply

Working with lists of dataframes like so

```
library(data.table)
IDn = c("ChrM", "ChrM" ,"ChrM" ,"ChrM" ,"ChrM")   
posn = c(2,5,7,8,9)
met = c(2,0,4,1,0)
nmet = c(2,1,0,2,0)
bd = c(3,3,0,8,10)
dfp = data.frame(IDn,posn,met,nmet,bd)
  IDn     posn met  nmet bd
1 ChrM    2    2    2    3
2 ChrM    5    0    1    3
3 ChrM    7    4    0    0
4 ChrM    8    1    2    8
5 ChrM    9    0    0    10
L1<-list(d1=dfp, d2=dfp, d3=dfp)
    $d1
   IDn posn met nmet bd
1 ChrM    2   2    2  3
2 ChrM    5   0    1  3
3 ChrM    7   4    0  0
4 ChrM    8   1    2  8
5 ChrM    9   0    0 10

$d2
   IDn posn met nmet bd
1 ChrM    2   2    2  3
2 ChrM    5   0    1  3
3 ChrM    7   4    0  0
4 ChrM    8   1    2  8
5 ChrM    9   0    0 10

$d3
   IDn posn met nmet bd
1 ChrM    2   2    2  3
2 ChrM    5   0    1  3
3 ChrM    7   4    0  0
4 ChrM    8   1    2  8
5 ChrM    9   0    0 10
```

I want to change, for example, the name of the bd column to bd and the name of the df;

I tried using `lapply` and `paste0("bd",names(l1))`, but this one adds up the 3 names when I only need one per df.

Comment: Easily doable, but why would you want to do this? That means that you will end up having additional data stored in a variable name beyond just the variable name. Why not add a column with the "name" of the `data.frame` instead?

Comment: Sorry, I oversimplified. I added another column with a conditional 
`L1 <- lapply(df, function(x) x[, crit := as.numeric((met + nmet >= cA) & (met>=bd))])`
So now I need to change the name of the `crit` columns to something unique to be able to compare them when I collapse them into a single table.

Comment: Since you have "data.table" loaded, just use `rbindlist` with `idcol = TRUE` to show where the data came from.

Comment: I want to make a table by merging columns, not rows

Comment: You can always go from "long" to "wide" later on if you need to using `dcast`. Also, you seem to be using `data.table` syntax with `data.frame`s--and using it incorrectly. If you've used `:=`, you shouldn't also need `<-`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `Map` to wrap the logic that you alluded to in the question:

```
Map(function(df,i) {names(df)[5] <- paste0("bd", names(L1)[i]);df}, L1, 1:length(L1))
# $d1
#    IDn posn met nmet bdd1
# 1 ChrM    2   2    2    3
# 2 ChrM    5   0    1    3
# 3 ChrM    7   4    0    0
# 4 ChrM    8   1    2    8
# 5 ChrM    9   0    0   10
# 
# $d2
#    IDn posn met nmet bdd2
# 1 ChrM    2   2    2    3
# 2 ChrM    5   0    1    3
# 3 ChrM    7   4    0    0
# 4 ChrM    8   1    2    8
# 5 ChrM    9   0    0   10
# 
# $d3
#    IDn posn met nmet bdd3
# 1 ChrM    2   2    2    3
# 2 ChrM    5   0    1    3
# 3 ChrM    7   4    0    0
# 4 ChrM    8   1    2    8
```

For `data.table` you can try:

```
for(i in 1:length(L1)) setnames(L1[[i]], "bd", paste0("bd", names(L1)[i]))
```

Comment: I added for `data.table`. I think the for loop is the quickest way for that case.